# Iterate through temp table and insert into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that returns `ID`, `ORG ID` and `NAME`.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP (ORG_ID INT)

INSERT INTO #TMP SELECT ORG_ID FROM [dbo].[fx_Rights_OrgIDs] (331)

SELECT [BRN_ID],[BRN_ORGID],[BRN_Name]
FROM [dbo].[BranchDetails]
WHERE [BRN_ORGID] IN (SELECT ORG_ID FROM #TMP)

DROP TABLE #TMP
```

Returns:

```
BRA_ID    BRA_ORGID     BRA_Name

289      333            Office

290      334            Store
```

What I want to do is Iterate through #TMP and insert into another table: `SitePrefix` if the value exists in `SitePrefix` don't insert.

So for example insert `BRA_Name` from `temp table` into `SitePrefix` and if it exists then skip.

`SitePrefix` columns looks like this: (`SPF_ID`,`SPF_Name`,`SPF_Prefix`)

`SPF_ID` is auto generated, `SPF_Name` should come from BRA_Name and the `SPF_Prefix` is `EMS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query which uses `EXCEPT` which is SET Difference operator in SQL Server

```
INSERT INTO SitePrefix  
   SELECT [BRN_Name], 'EMS'
   FROM [dbo].[BranchDetails]
   WHERE [BRN_ORGID] IN (SELECT ORG_ID FROM #TMP)
   EXCEPT
   SELECT SPF_Name, 'EMS'
   FROM SitePrefix
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,any problem then tell,

```
MERGE siteprefix AS T 
using (SELECT [brn_id], 
              [brn_orgid], 
              [brn_name] 
       FROM   [dbo].[branchdetails] 
       WHERE  [brn_orgid] IN (SELECT org_id 
                              FROM   [dbo].[Fx_rights_orgids] (331))) AS s 
ON t.spf_name = brn_name 
WHEN NOT matched THEN 
  INSERT (spf_name, 
          spf_prefix) 
  VALUES (brn_name, 
          brn_orgid)
```